# How to set admin settings in custom module in drupal 7

Tags: views

I have inserted some html div tags in page.tpl.php file which expands on mouse click. I want to make dynamic style like widh, height or margin from top left/right via admin setting form.
I have created admin setting form. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Could you expand a bit on what you've already tried please? There are several steps involved, and a non-trivial amount of code, it's very unlikely someone will just write a complete solution for you. If you can make the question less broad it'll save it from being closed as, quite aptly, "Too Broad". Please see the [help centre](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to construct a question that suits our Q+A format (a large part of it being the requirement that you show your research and efforts so far as part of the question). Thanks

Comment: Thank Clive for the quick response. I just want to set div style using admin setting form values. Thanks

Comment: OK I guess you didn't read the comment fully? What you'd like to accomplish is pretty clear, but it's not a trivial task, and no-one here is going to give you a full solution as it involves a fair amount of code and configuration. Do some research, try some things yourself, and when you have a **specific** question about your implementation that's when to ask here. You're currently asking us to code an entire feature of your site for you, and that's not something we can do for you here. If you can't provide that info I'm afraid this will be closed as "Too broad"

Comment: @Clive if you understand what OP tries to do, maybe you could edit this question? I think I might have seen helper module for that, but I'm only about 30% sure if I understand what *that* is in the first place.

Comment: Some little guidance could help me a lot. BTW Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Anuranjan_cws Okee dokee - you'll need to learn about the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/group/form_example/7) (and [`system_settings_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) specifically), the [menu system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for getting your page going, and [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) for extracting your saved config.

Comment: When you've read through all the documentation for those, and have a form working, please edit your question with the specific problems you're having (if you're still having them by that point). But have a good search around this site first to make sure your question hasn't already been answered - most of the basics like this have been covered many, many times :)

Comment: @Mołot I think we're good, the question couldn't be much clearer (to my befuddled Friday brain, anyway)

Comment: @Clive- I have created setting forms and it saves the setting too, and I also know how to get values from variable_get() from table variables. My question is , I am pulling variables using variable_get() in page.tpl.php and then set style options, is this a standard way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.